# Check if $\Bbb{Z}[1/2]$ is local or not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let me consider $R=\Bbb{Z}[1/2]$. I need to check if it is local or not.

I know that $R=\{p(1/2):p\in \Bbb{Z}[X]\}$ but I don't see where to start when I want to show if there is a unique maximal ideal or not. I know that the the maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ are $(p)$ where $p\in \Bbb{Z}[X]$ is irreducible, but can I use this to find the maximal ideals of $R$?

It would be nice if you could help me where to start because I really do not see where I should start.

Comment: A commutative ring is local, if and only if its non-units form an ideal. I would try and use that. What kind of integers are units/non-units in $R$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry we haven't had this statement is there also another possible approach

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I saw the following fact: $\mathbb Z[1/2]\cong \mathbb Z[x]/(2x-1)$ I think this also can be useful right?

Comment: You know all prime ideals of $\Bbb Z[1/2]$, namely $p\Bbb Z[1/2]$ for all primes $p>2$. And that $\Bbb Z[1/2]$ is $S^{-1}R$ with $R=\Bbb Z$ and $S=\{2^n\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see I think the maximal Ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ are not $(p)$ for $p$ irreducible

Comment: @DietrichBurde can you maybe tell me why we have the representation with the multiplicative set $S$

Comment: Yes, every maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has the form $(p, f(x))$ where $p$ is a rational prime and $f$ is a primitive polynomial that is irreducible modulo $p$. And for $S^{-1}R$, this is just by definition for a multiplicatively closed subset.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So is it always true that if I have a ring then $R[1/a]=S^{-1}R$ where $S=\{a^n\}$ or how does the definition works?

Comment: Every non-unit generates a proper ideal (the ring is commutative). Therefore every non-unit belongs to some maximal ideal (Zorn's lemon kinda argument there). If there is only a single maximal ideal, it must contain all the non-units (and obviously no units).

Comment: So if you can locate two non-units of $R$ such that their difference is a unit, you are done.

Comment: I see thank you